# Copy and paste values on the same row using for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste values on the same row, meaning i should have copied values("B3:I3") on the same row using the for loop.

I have tried Rows("J"  & (i+2) & ":J") and Offset() but it didnt work.

A3 gets a value, for example, if i enter a value of 5. The for loop should return the copied values("B3:I3") 5 times. But the return values are pasted on cells J3:Q6. I needed the return values to paste from J3:Q3, and the next record from R3:Y3 for the 2nd loop and Z3: AG3 for the 3rd loop

Appreciate everyone's advises as i am vba noob.

**Added comment at main post for clarity**

```
Private Sub AddItem()

Dim TotalItem As Variant
TotalItem = Range("A3").Value - 1

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To TotalItem

Range("B3:I3").Copy
Rows("J" & i + 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Did it do anything?  Throw an error, copy to the wrong range? What's the value in A3 when the code starts? Do you have the correct sheet selected - you don't specify so the code will use whatever sheet is active.

Comment: A3 gets a value, for example, if i enter a value of 5. The for loop should return the copied values("B3:I3") 5 times. But the return values are pasted on cells J3:Q6. 

I needed the return values to paste from J3:Q3, and the next record from R3:Y3 for the 2nd loop and Z3: AG3 for the 3rd loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this help instead?

```
Private Sub AddItem()

Dim TotalItem As Variant
TotalItem = Range("A3").Value - 1

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To TotalItem

Range("J3").Activate

    If i = 1 Then
        Range("B3:I3").Copy
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        Range("B3:I3").Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, (i - 1) * 8).Activate
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I got an error on this line  "ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues", debug error msg: "PasteSpecial Method of Range class failed"

Comment: Not sure why, it works when I do it. It could be that nothing was copied as far as the macro was concerned. Perhaps you could try putting the copy statement within the for loop so that it always copies - I have edited the original answer, could you see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not fully study the task, I hope this will do it.

```
Private Sub AddItem()
Dim TotalItem As Long
Dim rng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range("B3:I3")
    TotalItem = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value
    Dim lNumberOfCells As Long
    lNumberOfCells = rng.Cells.Count
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To TotalItem
        .Range("B3:I3").Offset(, i * lNumberOfCells).Value = .Range("B3:I3").Value
    Next i
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I tried changing this line " Range("B3:I3").Offset(i).Value = Range("B3:I3").Value"  to return each loop results next to each other.  The desired result should return from J3:Q3 for the first loop, R3:Y3 for the 2nd loop until the end of the for loop.